# Using jQuery to perform a post request and display the next following page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have setup a booking engine for a booking engine which uses a POST method - I have used a XDate library (which works great) my issue is that the booking engine should display the new page from the booking engine website after doing the POST.

I've added a jsbin link that illustrates the code
http://jsbin.com/ikowuk/1/

I am trying to implement the synxis booking engine similar to this site (albeit using jQuery)
http://www.stoneaston.co.uk/

```
function booking_engine(bookingObj)
{
  $.post('https://gc.synxis.com/rez.aspx', {
    'Chain': bookingObj.chain_id,
    'lang': '1',
    'locale': 'en-GB',
    'step': '1',
    'altdest': 'Country',
    'Hotel': bookingObj.booking_id,
    'arrive': bookingObj.start_date.uk_date,
    'depart': bookingObj.end_date.uk_date,
    'adult': bookingObj.adults,
    'child': bookingObj.child,
    'rooms': bookingObj.rooms
  }, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Just an idea, but you could make a **hidden** form, with hidden fields, then set the values of these fields to suit your requirements before simulating a submit. You won't need $.post(). You simply need to make your <form> tag have `method="POST" action="url-here"` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, just an option: you could make a form with the `hidden` attribute set.

`<form id="form1" action="https://gc.synxis.com/rez.aspx" method="POST" style="display: none;"><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></form>`
*(or alternative to hide)*

---

Then, instead of performing a jQuery `$.post()`, you could set the hidden elements of the form to the values you wish to post. So, for your example, one of the hidden elements added to the form could be:

`$('#form1').append('<input name="booking_id" type="text" value="'+bookingObj.booking_id+'">');`

Once you've created all your hidden elements and appended them to the hidden form, you submit that form:

`$('#submit').trigger('click');`

---

Once you trigger that click, all your data is then posted to your rez.aspx page and you also "go along with it".

Comment: Crazy.. after all that the booking engine accepts GET requests - thanks anyway your info is very useful!

Comment: @Zabs Cool! I've made the same mistake before - you *could* just change the method to "GET" if you wanted :) Either way, glad you've got it sorted.